# Solspace Calendar - Sticky Entry

Tags: solspace, solspace-calendar

I can't seem to figure out how to make an entry sticky using Solspace Calendar (particularly the exp:calendar:cal tag). Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Calendar does not support the "Sticky" feature unfortunately.